# How did Barzini not know of what was about to come?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-godfather

One question keeps bothering me. Tessio was a traitor. It is also well seen even before the Don died. It was his crew that was supposed to guard the hospital where Don was lying. Barzini also knew upfront that Luca is trying to infiltrate the family.

So, then why didn't Tessio rat the whole plan out? He was in the room when Michael suggested killing Sollozzo and the policeman. He didn't rat Michael out even when they found out where the restaurant is located. Or did he, and Barzini closed his eyes on that because it was what he wanted to happen? Or perhaps I'm wrong and Tessio became a traitor only after Don has died.